# C# Login Form, Login Button Doesn't Respond

Tags: c#, forms, authentication

So, I'm new to VS and C#, I'm self-teaching to get a better understanding of the backend of the product I work with. I created a small database with some information and a Login form. Everything appears to compile correctly, but the login button doesn't respond when clicked, neither does the cancel button for that matter. Not sure what I am missing, code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace CorpLogin
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //DB Connection String
        string cs = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CORPORATION.mdf;" +
        "Integrated Security=True";

    //Login Button clicked
    private void LoginButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Validates text entered
        if (userNameText1.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("USERNAME and PASSWORD are required fields.");
            return;
        }
        if (passwordText1.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("USERNAME and PASSWORD are required fields.");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            //Connect to SQL
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from USERS where USERNAME=@username" +
                "and PASSWORD=@password", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userNameText1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordText1.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
            int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

            //Show new form or fail message
            if (count == 1)
            {
                this.Hide();
                CorpView cv = new CorpView();
                cv.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ACCESS DENIED");
                }
            }
            //Catch program exceptions
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        //Cancel Button Clicked
        private void CancelButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Winforms? Also, which version of VS?

Comment: Did you by chance rename your button? The event handlers look okay.

Comment: go to the forms designer click on the button and then look at the events for this `LoginButton1_Click` click the dropdown for the button Click even and select that method.. otherwise double click on the Button Click Event and let the IDE create it automatically for you

Comment: You need to check to make sure you have that method assigned to the `Click` Event of each of those buttons. (The lightning bolt icon in the properties window)

Comment: If you leave the username or the password fields blank did you see the message boxes or not?

Comment: Thank you all, this helped so much. I'm getting a db connection error now, but that's within my realm. 

I assigned the click event for both buttons, the cancel works great. The login needs a little work, but as I said I can troubleshoot the connection. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to add the event handler Registration.

This can be done in the designer by double-click the button, or manually in your form:

```
LoginButton1.Click += new System.EventHandler(LoginButton1_Click);
```

Answer (score 0):

So the cause of my issue was as mentioned above. I did not have the event handlers mapped to the buttons. From the designer, I looked up the properties and selected the event methods (lightning bolt icon), in click I set the login button to LoginButton1_Click and on the cancel button I set it to CancelButton1_Click.

I am running into an error with the database connection, but I know how to troubleshoot that. The cancel button closes the program as expected.